# Иконки в Android Studio

Tags: android, иконки

Мне необходимы иконки 4 размеров – ldpi, mdpi, hdpi и xdpi. Они будут равны 24dp, 32dp, 48dp и 64dp соответственно.

- 1) Как их правильно создавать в Photoshop и импортировать, что бы при сжатии не было потери качества для каждого размера(Ибо в Photoshop'e они в px)?
- 2) Если брать уже готовые иконки в Android Studio, то лучше создавать 4 разных размера для одного layout'a, или создавать картинку одного размера и 4 разных layout'а? А может даже и 4 иконки, и 4 layout'a?

Comment: 1) указанные вами размеры и должны быть в px, а не dp (иначе на экране с бОльшей плотностью пикселя картинка физически будет больше и может не поместиться, либо будет уменьшаться до нужных размеров и искажаться  соответственно, плюс памяти займёт больше).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше всего публиковать один вопрос, а не вопрос состоящий из вложенных вопросов. По поводу картинок:

1. Как хотите так и создавайте картинки, это не очень понятный вопрос, и к программированию на Android он относится слабо. От себя могу добавить что лучше всего импортировать изображения в формате `svg` так как он лучше всего поддается редактированию из студии:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 2. Есть разные мнения по поводу второй части вашего вопроса - кто-то создает кучу макетов для разных разрешений и картинки соответственно, у кого-то нет времени и добавляют поддержку разных экранов из под одного макета. Вот документация: [ссылка_1](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) и [ссылка_2](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio)

На мой взгляд проще всего добавить картинку в `svg` и она будет нормально масштабироваться. Этот тип файлов - векторная графика, которая довольно гибкая в настройке и подгонке для ваших нужд ([доки](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources)).